# How To Group Columns and Use It Under One Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset like this:

| InTrafficA | OutTraffic A | InTrafficB | OutTrafficB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 12500 | 15000 | 20000 |

Is it possible to convert the output to something like this?

| Class | InTraffic | OutTraffic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10000 | 12500 |
| B | 15000 | 20000 |

Important thing is that I work for a strict company for security so creating views or using any other command than “SELECT” is not allowed.

And my query is written in the scheme down below:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT InTrafficA, OutTrafficA FROM SAME_TABLE) AS A
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT InTrafficB, OutTrafficB FROM SAME_TABLE) AS B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `VALUES` table construct to unpivot the data:

```sql
SELECT V.Class,
       V.InTraffic,
       V.OutTraffic
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('A', YT.InTrafficA, YT.[OutTraffic A]), --Don't put spaces in column names
                        ('B', YT.InTrafficB, YT.OutTrafficB)) V(Class, InTraffic, OutTraffic);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` operation in SQL without creating views or using any other command than `SELECT`.

```
CREATE TABLE #TrafficData (
    InTrafficA INT,
    OutTrafficA INT,
    InTrafficB INT,
    OutTrafficB INT
);

INSERT INTO #TrafficData (InTrafficA, OutTrafficA, InTrafficB, OutTrafficB)
VALUES (10000, 12500, 15000, 20000);


SELECT 'A' AS Class,
    InTrafficA AS InTraffic,
    OutTrafficA AS OutTraffic
FROM #TrafficData
UNION
SELECT 'B' AS Class,
    InTrafficB AS InTraffic,
    OutTrafficB AS OutTraffic
FROM #TrafficData;

DROP TABLE #TrafficData;
```